# INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Tags: trigger

Can you please help us below error.

> INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses,null].

Relevant `Apex Trigger` below:

```
trigger EmailNotification  on Task(after update){
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task tsk: Trigger.New){
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed'&&Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById ){
            ownerIds.add(tsk.CreatedById);     
        }       
    } 

    // Build a map of all users who are assigned the tasks
    Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name, Email, Manager.Email from User where Id in :ownerIds]);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMsglist=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();    

    for(Task tsk : Trigger.New){
        if(tsk.Status == 'Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById){
            User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
              String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email,theUser.Manager.email}; // (theUser.Manager.email),Changes Regarding US-01821/W-000220            
                mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);    // Set the TO addresses 
                mail.setSubject('A Task has been updated');   // Set the subject 
                // Next, create a string template. Specify {0}, {1} etc. in place of actual values.
                String template = 'Hello {0}, \n\nYour Task has been Completed. Here are the details - \n\n';
                template+= 'Subject: '+'"'+tsk.Subject+'"'+' \n';
                template+='Status: '+tsk.Status +' \n';
                template+='Priority: '+tsk.Priority +' \n';
                template+='DueDate: '+tsk.ActivityDate+'\n';
                template+='Comments: '+tsk.Description +'\n';
                template+='Related To: '+tsk.WhatID+' \n'; //Changes Regarding STN-00004755
                template+='\n\nFor more details, click the following link: \n';
                template+=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + tsk.Id;   

            List<String> args = new List<String>();     
            args.add(theUser.Name);
            // Here's the String.format()
            String formattedHtml = String.format(template, args);
            mail.setPlainTextBody(formattedHtml);
            emailMsglist.add(mail);  
        } 
    } 
    Messaging.SendEmail(emailMsglist);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the selected user doesn't have a manager, and thus the field is null. You'll need to build your list incrementally.

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] { theUser.Email };
if(theUser.Manager.Email != null) {
    toAddresses.add(theUser.Manager.email);
}
```

However, a *better* option is to use setTargetObjectIds by way of the [MassEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) class; this will allow you to not use your 1,000 email per day limit.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox,   Can you please tell me where i need to use the above condition on my existing trigger.

Comment: @sfdcfox In order to get the unlimited emailing capability mentioned in the second bullet https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_mass.htm&language=en_US you have to use the MassEmailMessage class instead of the SingleEmailMessage class? I am assuming because it is SF Id driven in the setTargetObjectIds method?

Comment: @JesseMilburn Yes, emailing "external addresses" counts towards the daily limit, but emailing "users" does not.

Comment: @Chinna Just put that code in place where you're declaring the toAddresses variable.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for Your help...I need one more help on this..We want to know sending email notification certain role level can you please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: @Chinna You'll have to query the database for all users in that role; if you're not sure, you might want to ask a new question with the code you have so far so we can properly address it.